# How to set Weather icons for Night and Day both on Android

Tags: android, icons, weather

I am making a weather app. Whole app is done and everything is working fine except NIGHT ICONS. I have set icons for the day. But I don't how to set two different icons on one condition that checks the time, if its day it shows SUN & if its night it should show MOON

Here is my code:

```
private static String updateWeatherIcon(int condition) {

    if (condition >= 0 && condition < 300) {
        return "tstorm1";
    } else if (condition >= 300 && condition < 500) {
        return "light_rain";
    } else if (condition >= 500 && condition < 600) {
        return "shower3";
    } else if (condition >= 600 && condition <= 700) {
        return "snow4";
    } else if (condition >= 701 && condition <= 771) {
        return "fog";
    } else if (condition >= 772 && condition < 800) {
        return "tstorm3";
    } else if (condition == 800) {
        return "sunny";
    } else if (condition >= 801 && condition <= 804) {
        return "cloudy2";
    } else if (condition >= 900 && condition <= 902) {
        return "tstorm3";
    } else if (condition == 903) {
        return "snow5";
    } else if (condition == 904) {
        return "sunny";
    } else if (condition >= 905 && condition <= 1000) {
        return "tstorm3";
    }

    return "dunno";
}
```

please help me out.

Comment: How is your code related to day or night? It's only weather condition. So can you please post how you get day/night And btw you don't need to do  `if (condition >= x && condition < y)` as it's an if/else with only values always higher than the previous condition. So you can do  `if (condition <= y)` instead.

Comment: see with weather conditions it uses that icon like if weather condition is 800 it return sunny icon. these conditions are in openweather API. what i want to do is if conditions == 800 i wanna return sunny in day and moon icon in night. so can you tell me how i can do that ?@Eselfar

Comment: You need to know what time is it in the location you try to get the weather from. Base on that you can define if it's day or night. Then you can choose the appropriate icon. Donno if the time is returned by the API but otherwise you can find another way to know it.

Comment: can u explain how i get time and set icon according to the time ? @Eselfar

Answer (score 3):

Guys i have found my Solution Thank you all

```
 long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            if(currentTime>=sunrise && currentTime<sunset) {
                return "sunny";
            } else {
                return "nighticon";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The weather API would never return "sunny" on the night time. So, you may not need to worry about it.

2) OpenWeather API returns the icon code in the response - "icon":"04n"
They have a set of weather icons listed in https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
which you can use or mimic. They do have different icons for day and night.

Hope that helps!

Comment: They return Clear in day and even in night too. so there is no way to set icon that way.

Comment: go through this documentation https://openweathermap.org/current, you dont need to check the condition to determine the icon. the api directly gives you the icon "04n" for night and "04d" for day. i have implemented it successfully using this.

Answer (score 0):

1. The openweathermap it self allow the trick for setting night and day icons.
   please refer ti that link https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
2. In the response we get iconId by that we can separate that icons....

hope it will help you